# Pass values to a PHP with jQuery POST

Tags: jquery, post, fullcalendar

All,
Say I have the following bit of code:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
    if (title) {
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
            {
                title: title,
                start: start,
                end: end,
                allDay: allDay
            },
            true // make the event "stick"
        );
        alert(start);
        jQuery.post("save_calendar_event.php", {
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            allDay: allDay
            }, function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    }
    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```

Then I have a PHP page to accept the post values:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start_time = $_POST['start'];
echo "The start time is: ".$start_time;
```

If I echo back the $title it works fine but if I do the $start_time it says the value isn't there. When the alert is shown for the start on the jQuery side it has the data that I'm looking to pass. Why won't it pass this variable to my PHP page?

***EDIT***: If I do the alert my alert shows: Sun Jan 29 2012 12:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

Thanks!

Comment: Use your browser's network monitoring tools to inspect the POST parameters sent to your PHP script. Is `start` set correctly?

Comment: in your php, do a `print_r($_POST)`. maybe your `start` variable is being indexed differently then you think.

Comment: It says "the value isn't there"? No really, what exactly does it say? Also, what does `var_dump($_POST)` give you?

Comment: Wait, are `start` and `end` [Javascript `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects?

Comment: @Phil I believe they are, does that make a difference?

Comment: @user1048676 See Rezigned's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to force convert your `start` and `end` js date time object to `string/timestamp` first (before send to $.post).

```
start.valueOf(); // for timestamp or shortcut +start
start.toUTCString() // to date format e.g. Wed, 01 Feb 2012 03:04:15 GMT
```

@Kai Qing I think jQuery already encoded parameters for you.

Comment: @Phil Thanks, so I'm not sure how to use that specifically. How would I do this before I send it using POST?

Comment: @user1048676 Just use the appropriate method in your `post()` data object, eg `{ title: title, start: start.toUTCString(), end: end.toUTCString(), allDay: allDay }`

Comment: @Phil Thanks, that does work. However I do just have one question. I'm in the central time zone so it's make the values 6 hours later then I want it. Is there a way to make it say take 6 hours off of that?

Comment: @user1048676 Send the [timezone offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) as well so your PHP script can determine the correct time and zone or use `toLocaleString()`

Answer (score 0):

Edited. See rezigned's answer. This method will work but is not proper:

Try replacing your post data object with this:

```
{ title: encodeURIComponent(title), start: encodeURIComponent(start), end: encodeURIComponent(end), allDay: encodeURIComponent(allDay) }
```

Then don't forget to urldecode() on your php side before doing anything with that data.

Comment: You do not need to do this at all. jQuery encodes the POST data correctly

Comment: @Phil actually, Kai was right. I did have to do that for the data to get passed correctly. When I did that the data was able to be used.

Comment: @user1048676 I've just tested this and it is in no way required.

Comment: @Phil - Hey I'm not saying it makes sense. I'm just suggesting it cause I've worked with jquery every day of my life for the past 3 years. I don't always have time to figure out why exactly or how but I do know some oddball tricks that seem to work. This being one. You can downvote all you want but a solution is a solution. If you know the proper fix, please add it as an answer and I will upvote you.

Comment: @KaiQing All you're doing is converting the `Date` objects to their string equivalent indirectly via `encodeURIComponent()`. Encoding the values is not required. Rezigned beat me to it, upvote his answer :)

Comment: Fair enough. I assume you're not posting an answer because Rezigned already has. I will upvote him.